# How to remove header and sidenav in a master page?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a master page created - wrap.master that has many content pages attached to it. Now I want to create a new content page and attach to it. The master page has a header and side nav. But in my new content page, I don't want the header and side nav. Typically, I want my content page to be linked to master page but without the the header and side nav(which means just footer alone). Can someone please tell me how to remove them with respect to my content page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would create a second master page, for the new layout.

If the footer is common to both master pages, which it sounds like it is, then I would put the footer in a user control and include that in both master pages.

(You should probably consider putting your header and navigation in a usercontrol as well. )

Another way to do this, would be to use a separate stylesheet for that page specifically. And in that stylesheet, you hide header and navigation (and footer).

Comment: Hello Oliver, thanks for this. But I just got to know that the footer is also not required. So I need literally a blank page linked with the master page.

Comment: If that's the case, don't use a master page at all.

Comment: Yeah that's what I am doing now, I just wanted to know if the previous thing is possible.

Comment: I just updated my answer, you could use a separate stylesheet.